# Is the rrule YEARLY broken for leap days?

Tags: python, python-dateutil, rrule

Suppose I wanted to get when to celebrate birthdays with rrule. Then the frequency YEARLY works fine, except for leap days. There it is in fact only every 4 years.

Is there any way to deal with it directly with rrule?

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, YEARLY

n = 1
print(list(rrule(freq=YEARLY, count=n + 1, dtstart=datetime(1990, 4, 28))))
print(list(rrule(freq=YEARLY, count=n + 1, dtstart=datetime(1992, 2, 29))))
```

gives

```
[datetime.datetime(1990, 4, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1991, 4, 28, 0, 0)]
[datetime.datetime(1992, 2, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1996, 2, 29, 0, 0)]
```

The fact that leap days are not even mentioned [in the docs](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html) makes me wonder if this might simply be a bug.

### byyearday

This might help, but only for the 28th of February:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, YEARLY

n = 5

bday = datetime(1990, 4, 28)
print(list(rrule(freq=YEARLY,
                 byyearday=bday.timetuple().tm_yday,
                 count=n + 1,
                 dtstart=bday)))

bday = datetime(1992, 2, 29)
print(list(rrule(freq=YEARLY,
                 byyearday=bday.timetuple().tm_yday,
                 count=n + 1,
                 dtstart=bday)))
```

gives

```
[datetime.datetime(1990, 4, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1991, 4, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1992, 4, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1993, 4, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1994, 4, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1995, 4, 28, 0, 0)]
[datetime.datetime(1992, 2, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1993, 3, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1994, 3, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1995, 3, 1, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1996, 2, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(1997, 3, 1, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: Looks like so.  Your answer is "yes".

Comment: It is broken. You can help checking if an issue already existis reporting this at https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues, otherwise filling up a new issue. Please, post the issue number back here in the comments if you do so.

Comment: The 3rd party code behavior questioned about is indeed broken. No answer can help but a PR to the project.

Comment: I posted it as an issue here: https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/823

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design and is in fact prominently mentioned in [the rrule documentation](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/rrule.html#dateutil.rrule.rrule), in the note that says:

> Per RFC section 3.3.10, recurrence instances falling on invalid dates
> and times are ignored rather than coerced:
>
> > Recurrence rules may generate recurrence instances with an invalid
> > date (e.g., February 30) or nonexistent local time (e.g., 1:30 AM on a
> > day where the local time is moved forward by an hour at 1:00 AM). Such
> > recurrence instances MUST be ignored and MUST NOT be counted as part
> > of the recurrence set.

Since February 29th, 1991 never existed, it is an invalid date and is skipped.

This is a limitation of the obsolete [RFC 2445](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2445), which was later supplanted by [RFC 5545](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545), which is updated by [RFC 7529](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7529). RFC 7529, among other things, adds the `SKIP` parameter to recurrence rules, which allows you to specify `OMIT` (default), `BACKWARD` or `FORWARD`. `dateutil` pre-dates RFC 7529 (and even RFC 5545), and is still in the process of being updated. You can track the progress on [issue #285](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/285).

This particular issue is addressed in [PR #522](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/pull/522), but that PR is still missing support for one fallback case and has not (as of October 2018) been merged.

For the simple case of a function that returns the same day on each year, falling back to the last day of the month, I recommend instead using `relativedelta` (until a version with SKIP functionality is released):

```
from dateutil import relativedelta
from datetime import datetime

def yearly_rule(dtstart, count=None):
    n = 0
    while count is None or n < count:
        yield dtstart + relativedelta.relativedelta(years=n)
        n += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for dt in yearly_rule(datetime(1992, 2, 29), count=5):
        print(dt)

    # Prints:
    # 1992-02-29 00:00:00
    # 1993-02-28 00:00:00
    # 1994-02-28 00:00:00
    # 1995-02-28 00:00:00
    # 1996-02-29 00:00:00
```

Note that I am using the **base datetime** (`dtstart`) in my rule rather than adding 1 year to the previous result. The reason for this is that `relativedelta` is lossy, so adding `relativedelta(years=1)` to `datetime(1995, 2, 28)` will give `datetime(1996, 2, 28)`.

Comment: Ah, it is RFC-7529

Comment: @MartinThoma My mistake, I was going from memory of what was in the 5545 and 7529. 7529 is an update to 5545, which is a replacement for 2445. I've updated the post. Thanks!